# custom joomla site, layout of a page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a quick question about the layout of the page on a custom joomla site. been googling to no avail. On the home page of a site im working on, i have a flash(or soon to be jquery ) banner with some of the products sold from my clients store hard coded onto the page.

looks good and all but, it appears in every page. now i know that modules can be appended to individual pages but, how can i make.....well for example, WordPress has a feature where you can make a template of a page and give that template to a new page.

is there something similar in joomla? my overall goal is to have this banner only appear on the homepage. the rest of the pages will only get the header,menu, middle content, footer etc.

im trying to find a workaround and so i was thinking of maybe creating a "custom html" module, and i guess copy/pasting the content there and praying that it works...i suppose if it did, then id be able to dictate what page that banner comes in at but this method seems too messy.

any ides on how to better achive this? im a noob to joomla so sorry if i seem a bit turned around.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want banner on home page only but not on other pages then just set the Banner module to show on home page only. You will get Menu option under Module configuration page.

For banner you can either use any third party Joomla modules or you can write your code inside custom HTML. I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good explanation about assigning modules:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_module_to_specific_pages%3F

If your scenario gets too complicated you can use an extension like this one to manage where (even when) your modules will be displayed:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307